# How to debug my ndis filter with windbg?

Tags: windbg, kernel-mode

I've configured the host and target machine correctly,

I can only connect to the target OS from the host machine.

And I've installed my ndis filter on the target machine.

How can I trace the process how my ndis filter works from here on?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?   If you connected windbg you can hit CTRL+Break set breakpoints, single-step.  You can also use debug prints or WPP tracing.